# Is it possible to build my query with only one select statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Below is my query and its output. Is it possible to build my query with only one select statement (I have two in my query)? It's for performance purposes.

```
WITH GradePassFail AS (
    SELECT 
        Subject, 
        Grade, 
        CASE WHEN Grade >= 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Pass, 
        CASE WHEN Grade < 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Fail 
    FROM Grade_report
)
SELECT Subject, MAX(Grade) AS Grade, SUM(Pass) AS Pass, SUM(Fail) AS Fail
FROM GradePassFail
GROUP BY Subject
```

[image]

Comment: the database will optimize the statement. If this can be written with a single statement (which it can), the database will rewrite this one to be optimal.

Comment: @kevin - Don't remove the details of the question so that your question may help other people also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform the `CASE` statements for Pass/Fail within the `SUM` function... then you don't need the CTE:

```
SELECT
    Subject,
    MAX(Grade) Grade,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Grade >= 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pass,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Grade < 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fail
FROM
    Grade_report
GROUP BY Subject
```

You can verify here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99cd4/7

Comment: @kevin If you look at the execution plan, you'll see that they are identical. What you just did was so-called [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) - basically you wasted time on a non-issue and even arguably sacrificed some readability for that.